# Polygon function in R creates a line between first and last point

Tags: r, plot, time-series, polygon

I have a time series that I'd like to plot using the polygon function as I want to create a shade between different time series. However, when calling `polygon ()`, the function adds a line between the first and last point (in essence it connects the first and last point to finish the plot). I would like to know how to tell R not to join up the two. Slightly related questions have been posted ([Line connecting the points in the plot function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700186/line-connecting-the-points-in-the-plot-function-in-r)) but the solutions didn't help. Any help would be appreciated.

I have already tried several things, such as reordering the data like in the part below.

% ts_lb_vec is my time-series in vector format;

% x is a vector of time (2000 to 2015);

% I first call plot which plots x (time) with y (the time-series). This works fine;

```
plot(x, ts_lb_vec,type='n',ylim=c(-300,300), ylab="", xlab="")
```

But if I want to use the polygon function to use the shading capabilities, it draws the line and I have tried reordering the data (as below) to try to eliminate the problem but this is unsuccessful

```
polygon(x[order(x),ts_lb_vec[order(x)], xlim=range(x), ylim=range(ts_lb_vec))
```

I would just like R when calling the polygon function to not connect my first and last point (see image). The figure attached bellow was produced using the following code:

```
plot(x, ts_lb_vec,type='n', ylab="", xlab="")
polygon(x, ts_lb_vec)
```

[image]

Just to clarify, what I would like is for the space between two time series to be filled, hence why I need the function polygon. See image below[image]

Comment: The ends has to connect, otherwise it isn't really a polygon, and no way to tell what area should be shaded. You have to decide _how_ you want the ends to be connected.

Comment: OK, this makes sense but what I'd like is that the space between one timeseries and another is filled with a shade. I've attached a second image in the question to clarify. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I put together a solution using `ggplot2`.

The key step is drawing a separate polygon where the order of one of the curves is inverted to avoid the crossing over back to the start.

```
# simple example data
examp.df <- data.frame(time = seq_len(15), a  = c(1,2,3,4,5,5,5,4,3,2,4,5,6,7,8), b = c(2,4,5,6,7,8,7,6,6,5,6,4,3,2,1))

# the polygon is generated by inverting the curve b
polygon <- data.frame(time <- c(examp.df$time, rev(examp.df$time)), y.pos = c(examp.df$a, rev(examp.df$b)))

ggplot(examp.df) + 
  geom_polygon(data = polygon, aes(x = time, y = y.pos), fill = "blue", alpha = 0.25) + 
  geom_line(aes(x= time, y = a), size = 1, color = "red") + 
  geom_line(aes(x = time, y = b), size = 1, color = "green") + 
  theme_classic()
```

Which results in:
[image: two curves with a polygon in the middle]

If you want to know more about `ggplot2` this is a good [introduction](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/be-awesome-in-ggplot2-a-practical-guide-to-be-highly-effective-r-software-and-data-visualization).